# Mezclar Css con ASP c#

Tags: c#, css, asp

Quisiera saber si es posible mezclar código de C# con css en una hoja de estilo, en estos momento tengo esto:

```
 :root {
   --fond_Size: 14px !important; 
   --title_Size: 20px !important; 
   --padding_span: 5% !important; 
   --fond_Size_Popup: 30px !important;  
}
```

Quisiera algo como esto:

```
:root {
   --fond_Size: @ViewBag.Size + px !important; 
   --title_Size: 20px !important; 
   --padding_span: 5% !important; 
   --fond_Size_Popup: 30px !important;  
}
```

Cabe recalcar que habría que concatenar la palabra px, o algo así...

Comment: sí, es posible, siempre y cuando sean estilos dentro de una página .cshtml o .aspx

Comment: porque necesitas hacer algo como eso? la verdad no lo recomendaria. Se supone que el font deberias determinarlo de forma responsive del lado cliente, o quizas realizar una llamada ajax al servidor obtener el valor y asignarlo por jquery o javscript

Answer (score 0):

No puedes mezclar CSS y codigo C#, pero puedes cambiarle la propiedad de un control html con javascrips o en el momento que este se renderiza.

Dependiendo la manera en la cual renderizas la pantalla, sea por Webform, Razor, Asp, etc, es la tecnica que te conviene utilizar.

Te doy un ejemplo con Razor:

@if (ViewBag.Size == 0)
{
      
      
}
else
{
   
   
}